# Am I appropriately using dashes?

Tags: adjectives, dashes

> "I’m confident I’d excel in the position due to my prior experience and my involvement in extracurriculars-- learning to
> communicate with people from a variety of backgrounds and understanding myself as a "hybrid" kind of person, able to perform both technical and project
> management-related tasks, if you will."

Grammarly underlines the word `understanding` when I type it within my notes. Am I using it wrong?

Also, are the dashes appropriate?

Comment: Dashes are a separate question - you can look at the "dashes" tag and find a lot of relevant questions, but it is to a large extent a matter of style.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is reading it as "a variety of backgrounds and understanding" and trying to match the plurality of "backgrounds" with "understanding". Recommended action is to put a comma after "backgrounds".